# How to denote a set of vectors?

Tags: notation, vectors, article-writing

I have a set that contains vectors as its elements and would therefore like the [vectors to be in bold font](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9780470549094.app1). Still, I am not sure if the set should also be bold. Which one is more accurate, 1 or 2?

1. $\textbf{S}$ and $\textbf{s}_i$ are both bold :
   $$
   \textbf{S}=\{\textbf{s}_0, \textbf{s}_1, ...\} 
   $$
2. $S$ is not bold, but $\textbf{s}_i$ is bold:
   $$
   S=\{\textbf{s}_0, \textbf{s}_1, ...\} 
   $$

Again, $\textbf{s}_i$ needs to be in bold because it is a vector.

Comment: We usually denote vectors in bold, since $S$ is a set, I think it would be better to follow the usual set notation and denote $S$ for the set

Comment: Thanks. Totally agree. In this case it is no. 2?

Comment: Yes, the case in no. 2

Comment: While we're at it: Should it be $\mathbf s_0, \mathbf s_1, \dots$ or $\mathbf{s_0}, \mathbf {s_1}, \dots$? (the indices are bold in the second case)

Comment: I am NOT using bold for the numeral indices in my work. But I find your question very legit!

Comment: I think $S$ should not be bold: if you use bold face for vectors (i.e. tuples), then the intuition would be for $\mathbf S$ to be a tuple of sets. As for the indices: there is no reason why they should be bold; typographically speaking, texts should not use superfluous decorations as these draw the reader's attention away from the point.

Comment: Am I better of with a set of vectors, as I need to do some computation on each **`s`**  vector? With vectors I mean 1D arrays.

Comment: @Christoph The indices should not be bold. If you write them in bold when they’re numbers, I would expect you to also write in bold when they’re variables. But $\mathbf{s_i}$ looks like your index is the vector $\mathbf{i}$, which you probably don’t want.